# Match word by its prefix

Tags: regex, prefix

I'm trying to match a string by its prefix that ends with a particular character. For example, if my string is `"abcd"` and ends in `#`, then any word which is a prefix of `"abcd"` should be matched as long as it ends with `#`. Here are some examples to help illustrate the pattern:

**Input**: `"ab#"` gives `true` (as `"ab"` is a prefix of `"abcd"` and end with a `#`).

**Input**: `"abcd#"` gives `true` (as `"abcd"` is a prefix of `"abcd"` and end with a `#`).

**Input**: `"bc#"` gives `false` (as `"bc"` is a not a *prefix* of `"abcd"` ).

**Input**: `"ab@"` gives `false` (while `"ab"` is a *prefix* of `"abcd"`, it doesn't end with `#`) .

**Input**: `"ac#"` gives `false` (while `"ac"` is contained within `"abcd"`, it doesn't begin with a prefix from `"abcd"`) .

So far, I've managed to come up with the following expression which seems to be working fine:

```
/(abcd|abc|ab|a)#/
```

While this is working, it isn't very practical, as larger words of length `n` will make the expression quite large:

```
/(n|n-1|n-2| ... |1)#/
```

Is there a way to rewrite this expression so it is more scalable and concise?

Example of my attempt (in JS):

```js
const regex = /(abcd|abc|ab|a)#/; 

console.log(regex.test("abcd#")); // true
console.log(regex.test("ab#")); // true
console.log(regex.test("abc#")); // true
console.log(regex.test("abz#")); // false
console.log(regex.test("abc@")); // false
```

**Edit:** Some of the solutions provided are nice and do do what I'm after, however, for this particular question, I'm after a solution which uses pure regular expressions to match the prefix.

Comment: Why don't you use basic string manipulation to check this instead of regex?

Comment: @VLAZ Hi vlaz, you're right - I could. However, I'm looking trying to do this as a regex exercise (I probably shouldn't have tagged JS, I've removed the tag now)

Comment: Are you just testing if a string contains a word that matches your specifics or trying to extract that word? How many prefixes are we talking about?

Comment: @JonP I'm just testing to see if it is a prefix, no need to extract the word

Comment: Is the string the entire "word" or could the string be "here is my preword# here"?

Comment: @JonP You can treat it as the entire "word" (ie no additional text before it or after it)

Comment: Finally (I hope) is the entire word `prefix+#` or can it be `prefix+optionally arbitrary characters + #`?

Comment: @JonP The entire word will be `prefix+#` (so no optional characters between the prefix and #)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `String#startsWith` and `String#endsWith` here:

```
String input = "abcd";
String prefix = "ab#";

if (input.startsWith(prefix.replaceAll("#$", "")) && prefix.endsWith("#")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

**Edit:** A JavaScript version of the above:

```js
var input = "abcd";
var prefix = "ab#";

if (input.startsWith(prefix.replace(/#$/, "")) && prefix.endsWith("#")) {
   console.log("MATCH");
}
else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. This will definitely work and is a good solution. However, I'm currently looking for an answer using pure regex (above I've just used JS as an environment to test my regular expression(s)).

Comment: Regex isn't the best tool for everything.  While I lean towards using regex whenever possible, it does tend to underperform solutions using only base string functions.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for taking your time to assist me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a left field JavaScript option. Build and array of valid prefixes, use join on the array to make your regex pattern.

```js
var validPrefixes = ["abcd",
"abc", 
"ab", 
"a", 
"areallylongprefix"];

var regexp = new RegExp("^(" + validPrefixes.join("|") + ")#$");


console.log(regexp.test("abcd#"));// true
console.log(regexp.test("ab#")); // true
console.log(regexp.test("abc#")); // true
console.log(regexp.test("abz#")); // false
console.log(regexp.test("abc@")); // false
console.log(regexp.test("areallylongprefix#")); //true
```

This can be adapted to the language of tour choosing, also handy if your prefixes are dynamically retrieved from a database or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^ab?c?d?#$`

Explanation:

```
`^` - match beginning of a string

`b?` - match match zero or one `b`
```

Rest is analigocal to the above.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZVj8o/1)

Comment: This would match on "abd#", "acd#", "ac#", and "ad#". I believe these would be false positives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will match `ac#` (while `ac` is contained within the prefix it should only match `ac` if the word looks like "acbe" as that word starts with "ac" in this case, however, in the case above, it starts with `"ab"`)

Comment: I think you would need `^((((ab)?)c)?)d)?$`, but this starts to get unwieldy pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my c# attempt:

```
private static bool test(string v)
{
   var pattern = "abcd#";
   //No error handling
   return v.EndsWith(pattern[pattern.Length-1])
      && pattern.Replace("#", "").StartsWith(v.Replace("#",""));
}
```

```
Console.WriteLine(test("abcd#")); // true
Console.WriteLine(test("ab#")); // true
Console.WriteLine(test("abc#")); // true
Console.WriteLine(test("abz#")); // false
Console.WriteLine(test("abc@")); // false
Console.WriteLine(test("abc")); //false
```

Comment: `test("abc")` will return `true` but that's wrong. Same with `test("bcd#")`

Comment: @VLAZ I wasn't trying to show a bulletproof solution, but a non-regex approach. Having said that,  I expanded the code to cover the `abc` case.

Answer (score 0):

```
/a(b(cd?)?)?#/
```

Or for a longer example, to match a prefix of "abcdefg#":

```
/a(b(c(d(e(fg?)?)?)?)?)?#/
```

---

Generating this regex isn't completely trivial, but some options are:

```
function createPrefixRegex(s) {
    // This method creates an unnecessary set of parentheses
    // around the last letter, but that won't harm anything.
    return new RegExp(s.slice(0,-1).split('').join('(') + ')?'.repeat(s.length - 2) + '#');
}

function createPrefixRegex2(s) {
    var r = s[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < s.length - 2; ++i) {
        r += '(' + s[i];
    }
    r += s[s.length - 2] + '?' + ')?'.repeat(s.length - 3) + '#';
    return new RegExp(r);
}

function createPrefixRegex3(s) {
    var recurse = function(i) {
        if (i >= s.length - 1) {
            return '';
        }
        if (i === s.length - 2) {
            return s[i] + '?';
        }   
        return '(' + s[i] + recurse(i + 1) + ')?';
    }   

    return new RegExp(s[0] + recurse(1) + '#');
}
```

These may fail if the input string has no prefix before the '#' character, and they assume the last character in the string is '#'.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen 's comment was added while I was typing this, and it's pretty much the same.

Comment: I don't think this is much more scalable than the alternation OP used.

Comment: @VLAZ Meh, it's somewhat better for longer strings, at least as far as length is concerned. The OP solution's regex grows in length as O(n^2), while this should grow as O(n). The OP does have the advantage of being more legible, though.

Comment: It's also easier to automatically generate, since you just need to break up the full prefix by all sub-prefixes, reverse, and join with `"|"`. So even if the pattern grows in length faster, it's its creation can be trivially automated. This can also be automated but it's more annoying.

Comment: That's also true.